# Native Buffer on Raspberry Pi

Tags: c++, linux, opengl

I am currently porting a piece of software that was written for android (using the android NDK, so most parts are C++, except for the GUI) to the raspberry pi. The software involves OpenGL ES 2 using native buffers to avoid uploading every texture to use.

I am struggling with this line:

```
    buffer_ = new android::GraphicBuffer(width, height, fmt.get_android_format(), android::GraphicBuffer::USAGE_SW_WRITE_OFTEN | android::GraphicBuffer::USAGE_HW_TEXTURE);
```

Is there an equivalent for the raspberry pi? I am currently struggling with the GL Extensions and the documentations for that, what I found out so far is that in Linux you can use an `EGL_LINUX_DMA_BUF_EXT`, but i dunno how to find out if this is supported by the pi. Or is there any better way to create my buffer?

P.S.: The Buffer will be in the format `R5G6B5` later. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using http://www.mesa3d.org/opengles.html  ? Look at the examples: https://cgit.freedesktop.org/mesa/demos